# Uncrustify: Which switch or setting affects the { for @interface and @protocol?

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

I use Uncrustify to beautify my code:

http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

What switch or setting affects the `{` for `@interface` and `@protocol`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy setting for this. However, you can edit the templates that Xcode uses by following the instructions [here](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/making-custom-templates-for-xcode-4-march-2011/).

Comment: This is a question about uncrustify; not Xcode. I use uncrustify to clean up non-template code.

Comment: My apologies - I misread the question as you wanted to "uncrustify" the "@interface X {" declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `@protocol` has a curly brace - since there's no ivars in a protocol. 
However I have added this as a feature request [here](https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify/issues/126) so hopefully one day we get what we want :)